# The most general type of the following function in Haskell

Tags: haskell

There is `g = (. not)`.

And the most general type of the function `g` is

```
g :: (Bool -> a) -> Bool -> a
```

But I cannot get how to think the  composition `(.)` function.

Why is it not  `h :: (a -> Bool) -> a -> Bool`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
g = (. not)
```

is equivalent, by definition of the section, to

```
g = \f -> f . not
```

or to

```
g f = f . not
```

Since `f` takes as input the output of `not`, it must accept a boolean as input, hence it must have type `Bool -> something`.

From this, I think you can figure out the rest.

Note that `(. not)` is very different from `(.) not` which would be written as a section as `(not .)` (or, as a lambda, as `\f -> not . f`). I think your confusion originates from this.

Comment: Possibly related: We see `not . f` way more often in ordinary code than we see `f . not`, which may bias expectations when trying to quickly derive the type for `(. not)`. I certainly got it wrong at first glance.